# Concurrency problems with temp tables in consequent batches?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I have sometimes a problem when running a script. I have the probelm when using an application (that I didn't write and therefore cannot debug) that launches the scripts. This app isn't returning the full error from SQL Server, but just the error description, so I don't know exactly where th error comes.

I have the error only using this tool (it is a tool that sends the queries directly to SQL Server, using a DAC component), if I run the query manuallyin management studio I don't have the error. (This error moreover occurs only on a particular database).

My query is something like:

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP_TABLE
  FROM ANOTHER_TABLE 
GO

--some other commands here
GO

INSERT INTO SOME_OTHER_TABLE(FIELD1,FIELD2) 
  SELECT FIELDA, FIELDB
  FROM #TEMP_TABLE  

GO

DROP TABLE #TEMP_TABLE
GO
```

The error I get is #TEMP_TABLE is not a valid object

So somehow i suspect that the DROP statement is executed before the INSERT statement.

But AFAIK when a GO is there the next statement is not executed until the previous has been completed.

Now I suspoect that this is not true with temp tables... Or do you have another ideas?

Comment: How and where is the TEMP_TABLE table is declared and created?

Comment: @sll Its created on the first command on the script, the `SELECT * INTO #TEMP_TABLE FROM ANOTHER_TABLE` part

Comment: @Lamak: I believe you should do `CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLE` first

Comment: @sll It is a better practice to do a `CREATE TABLE`, but `SELECT INTO` is perfectly valid

Comment: @Lamak : cool, this is new for me, thanks! BTW, Are you have any references to MSDN?

Comment: @sll : Here is the link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187(v=sql.80).aspx#_into_clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is most likely caused by either an end of session prior to the `DROP TABLE` causing SQL Server to automatically drop the table or the `DROP TABLE` is being executed in a different session than the other code (that created and used the temporary table) causing the table not to be visible.

I am assuming that stored procedures are not involved here, because it looks like you are just executing batches, since local temporary tables are also dropped when a stored proc is exited.

There is a good description of local temporary table behavior in this article on [Temporary Tables in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/):

> You get housekeeping with Local Temporary tables; they are
>   automatically dropped when they go out of scope, unless explicitly
>   dropped by using DROP TABLE. Their scope is more generous than a table
>   Variable so you don't have problems referencing them within batches or
>   in dynamic SQL. Local temporary tables are dropped automatically at
>   the end of the current session or procedure. Dropping it at the end of
>   the procedure that created it can cause head-scratching: a local
>   temporary table that is created within a stored procedure or session
>   is dropped when it is finished so it cannot be referenced by the
>   process that called the stored procedure that created the table. It
>   can, however, be referenced by any nested stored procedures executed
>   by the stored procedure that created the table. If the nested
>   procedure references a temporary table and two temporary tables with
>   the same name exist at that time, which table is the query is resolved
>   against?

Comment: This is the kind of situation where you use SQL Profiler to watch and observe what is actually happening when the command(s?) are submitted. Besides the batch and statement begin and end events, include login and logout (which will show the connection's myriad SET settings, a good source of really obscure and irritating problems), as well as exception to pick up when the error actually occurs.

Comment: I think a quick and dirty trick is to remove the DROP TABLE statement, the table will be anyway dropped automatically and it is totally safe in my case to leave it there and not drop it. This is not a solution that works for sure because I am not sure that the error is given by the insert into or the drop table command, anyway in case it is given by the drop table this would be the solution. In case it is not I will try the profiler. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would start up SQL Profiler and verify if your tool uses one connection to execute all batches, or if it disconnects/reconnects. Also it could be using a connection pool.

Anyway, executing SQL batches from a file is so simple that you might develop your own tool very quickly and be better off.

Comment: I cannot develop the tool, or I let's say I could, but that tool is not a simple script launcher, it has also some logic in it and it is part of a commercial product. Yes the profiler is probably my only option, but the problrem is that this occurs here and there, it is not 100% reproducible and therefore even the producer of the product has a good excuse not to help me.